# Unable to run AWS StepFunctions inside an AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to start the execution of an AWS StepFunction from inside an AWS Lambda, but I receive `null` as result, with no error message. The StepFunctions here is an Express State Machine, so I use the method `startSyncExecution(params = {}, callback)`, as pointed in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/StepFunctions.html#startSyncExecution-property).

Here is the code of the Lambda:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        stateMachineArn: "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:[AccountID]:stateMachine:BookLectureStateMachine",
        input: JSON.stringify(event),
        name: "test-from-lambda"
    }
    
    var stepfunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions();

    console.log("Everything okay") //This one is logged

    stepfunctions.startSyncExecution(params, function(err, data) {

        console.log("This log isn't shown"); //This one isn't logged

        if (err) {
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 400,
                body: err,
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                }
            })
        } else {
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: 'Lecture booked',
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                }
            })
        }
    });
};
```

The response is `null`, nothing else.

I've checked the permissions, and the Lambda has Full Access to the Step Functions.

Any idea on how to solve it?

**UPDATE**

1. I think the StepFunction is not executed, since the logs are empty.
2. I increased the Lambda timeout to 1min in order to avoid timeout scenarios. The billed duration is about half a second

Comment: Is there anything else in the logs? Like something saying the function timed out?

Comment: Nope, I increased the timeout to one minute in order to avoid this scenario, and it doesn't expire. I update the question

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the mix of callbacks and `async`. Since you aren't using `await` in your handler anywhere, I would try removing `async` from the handler. Either that or you could try changing the code to `var data = await stepfunctions.startSyncExecution(params).promise()`

Comment: @MarkB It worked after removing the `async`. Post it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it may have something to do with the mix of callbacks and `async`. Since you aren't using `await` in your handler anywhere, I would try removing `async` from the handler.

Either that or you could try changing the code to:

```
var data = await stepfunctions.startSyncExecution(params).promise()
```